# How change the background of home page jupiter?

Tags: background

I was change the background of the home page jupiter with "jt -t chesterish" in Anaconda Prompt, but when I refresh the page stayed the same background.

I tried nothing because I am starting in the programming

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.